# How to add multiple divs with appendChild?

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I am trying to make a chessboard using javascript and creating 64 divs with it.
The problem is, that it creates only the first div.
Here is the code:

```
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;

    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function()
    {
        var i=0;
        var j=0;
        var d=document.createElement("div");

        for (i=1; i<=8; i++)
        {
            for (j=1; j<=8; j++)
            {
                if ((i%2!=0 && j%2==0)||(i%2==0 && j%2!=0))
                {
                    document.body.appendChild(d);
                    d.className="black";
                }
                else
                {
                    document.body.appendChild(d);
                    d.className="white";
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> The problem is, that it creates only the first div.

Right, because you've only created one `div`. If you want to create more than one, you must call `createElement` more than once. Move your

```
d=document.createElement("div");
```

line *into* the `j` loop.

If you call `appendChild` passing in an element that's already in the DOM, it's *moved*, not copied.

```
window.onload=function()
    {
        var i=0;
        var j=0;

        for (i=1; i<=8; i++)
        {
            for (j=1; j<=8; j++)
            {
                if ((i%2!=0 && j%2==0)||(i%2==0 && j%2!=0))
                {
                    var d=document.createElement("div");
                    document.body.appendChild(d);
                    d.className="black";
                }
                else
                {
                    var d=document.createElement("div");
                    document.body.appendChild(d);
                    d.className="white";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @SvyatoslavSykalo: Good deal, glad that helped!

Comment: Note this approach will cause page reflow (computation of element's position and geometry) every time you call `appendChild()`. Use `documentFragment` (see below) to batch append child.

Answer (score 78):

As t-j-crowder has noted, the OP's code only creates one div. But, for googlers, there is one way to append multiple elements with a single `appendChild` in the DOM: by creating a [`documentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createDocumentFragment).

```
function createDiv(text) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
  return div;
}

var divs = [
  createDiv("foo"),
  createDiv("bar"),
  createDiv("baz")
];

var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  docFrag.appendChild(divs[i]); // Note that this does NOT go to the DOM
}

document.body.appendChild(docFrag); // Appends all divs at once
```

Comment: Thanks!
Interesting, i'll try this one too.

Comment: You should always go with `documentFragment` when adding multiple elements. `documentFragment` acts as a staging area where you repeatedly add elements and, at last, you add it to the `DOM`. Repeatedly adding elements to the `DOM` will cause entire document reflow. See this: http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/

Answer (score 12):

Although what T.J. Crowder writes works fine, I would recommend rewriting it to the code below, using a documentFragment, like Renato Zannon suggested. That way you will only write to the DOM once.

```js
    window.onload = function() {
        var count = 5,
            div,
            board = document.getElementById('board'),
            fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        
        // rows
        for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i) { 

            // columns
            for (var j = 0; j < count; ++j) { 
                div = document.createElement('div');
                div.className = (i % 2 != 0 && j % 2 == 0) || (i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 != 0) ? 'black' : 'white';
                fragment.appendChild(div);
            }
        }
        
        board.appendChild(fragment);
    };
```

```css
#board {
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 510px;
  padding: 1px;
  width: 510px;
}

.black,
.white {
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 1px;
    width: 100px;
}

.black {
  background-color: #333;
}

.white {
  background-color: #efefef;
}
```

```html
<div id="board"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function crt_dv(){
dv=document.createElement('div'),document.body.appendChild(dv)
};

crt_dv(),dv.className='white';crt_dv(),dv.className='black';
```

Also use: for(i=0;i<2;i++)