# How to set a nodelist as innerHtml?

Tags: javascript, dom, nodelist

I have a nodelist, `nl`, and a `div#parent`.

How can I set all elements from `nl` as `div#parent`'s `innerHTML`?

Comment: Your question is phrased so as to assume the solution involves `innerHTML`, but in fact `innerHTML` is a sort of blunt knife that fills an element with DOM content represented as a huge string. A more general statement of your problem would be "How to set a nodelist as the content of an element?".

Comment: Check out [NodeList.js](https://github.com/eorroe/NodeList.js)

Answer (score 2):

Empty the parent first, then use appendChild to append a DOM element

```
parent.innerHTML = '';
parent.appendChild(nl);
```

for nodeLists containing several elements, iteration is needed

```
parent.innerHTML = ''; 

[].forEach.call(nl, function(item) {
    parent.appendChild(item);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/p7pssu2w/1/)

Comment: If `nl` is a NodeList, even if it only contains one node, then `appendChild` will not work.

Comment: use [documentFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14910308/3596672) instead of repeatedly calling appendChild to avoid unnecessary document reflow

Answer (score 2):

When nodelists are iterables, then you can do

```js
for (let node of nl) parent.appendChild(node);
```

See [Are HTMLCollection and NodeList iterables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31283360/are-htmlcollection-and-nodelist-iterables). In the meantime, you may have some luck with

```
NodeList.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = Array.prototype[Symbol.iterator];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a document fragment and append that instead.

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

while(nl.length) 
    fragment.appendChild(nl[0]);

parent.appendChild(fragment);
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jtnvn56w/3/)

Comment: The idea of using a fragment is good, but if the nodelist is "live", as is the case of `childNodes` as used in your fiddle, then this will work, because appending each element to the fragment will remove it from the list. However, if nodelist is **not** live, such as the return from `querySelectorAll`, then you'll end up with an infinite loop.