# Symbol.iterator is not a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
<div id="par">
    <span id="a1"></span>
    <span id="a2"></span>    
<div id="par2">     
    <span id="a3"></span>
    <span id="a4"></span>
</div>    
</div>

<script>


var ele = document.querySelectorAll('#par span');    

for( var p of ele ){
    console.log(p);
}


</script>
```

When i run this code I see error

> Uncaught TypeError: ele[Symbol.iterator] is not a function

How to fix this problem ?

Comment: @Rajesh: No, you cannot use `for in` for them

Comment: @Bergi You are right. My apologies.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Convert `NodeList` to `Array` for make it in iterable form, use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to convert it.

```html
<div id="par">
  <span id="a1"></span>
  <span id="a2"></span>
  <div id="par2">
    <span id="a3"></span>
    <span id="a4"></span>
  </div>
</div>


<script>
  var ele = document.querySelectorAll('#par span');

  for (var p of Array.from(ele)) {
    console.log(p);
  }
</script>
```

---

Refer the following question for more info : [Are HTMLCollection and NodeList iterables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31283360/are-htmlcollection-and-nodelist-iterables)