# Can HTMLCollections be iterated with for...of (Symbol.iterator)?

Tags: javascript, dom, language-lawyer, iterable, htmlcollection

DOM4 makes [NodeList](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#interface-nodelist)s iterable:

```
interface NodeList {
  getter Node? item(unsigned long index);
  readonly attribute unsigned long length;
  iterable<Node>;
};
```

According to [WebIDL](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#idl-iterable), this means

> Objects implementing an interface that is declared to be iterable
>   support being iterated over to obtain a sequence of values.
>
> Note: In the ECMAScript language binding, an interface that is
>   iterable will have “entries”, “forEach”, “keys”, “values” and
>   [@@iterator](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-well-known-symbols) properties on its [interface prototype object](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#dfn-interface-prototype-object).

So the following is possible:

```
for (var el of document.querySelectorAll(selector)) ...
```

I noticed the same seems to work for HTMLCollections, both on Firefox and Chrome:

```
for (var el of document.getElementsByTagName(tag)) ...
```

In fact, I get

```
HTMLCollection.prototype[Symbol.iterator] === [][Symbol.iterator]; // true
```

However, [HTMLCollection](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#interface-htmlcollection) is not defined as iterable:

```
interface HTMLCollection {
  readonly attribute unsigned long length;
  getter Element? item(unsigned long index);
  getter Element? namedItem(DOMString name);
};
```

I also checked the [WHATWG DOM spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-htmlcollection) and it's not iterable neither.

Then, is this behavior standard or not? Is `HTMLCollection` supposed to have an `@@iterator` in the prototype?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31574921/2813224

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found it, it's explained in [WebIDL](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#es-iterator):

> If the [interface](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#dfn-interface) has any of the following:
>
> - an [iterable declaration](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#dfn-iterable-declaration)
> - an [indexed property getter](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#dfn-indexed-property-getter) and an [integer-typed](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#dfn-integer-type) [attribute](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#dfn-attribute) named “length”
> - a [maplike declaration](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#dfn-maplike-declaration)
> - a [setlike declaration](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#dfn-setlike-declaration)
>
> then a property must exist whose name is the [@@iterator](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-well-known-symbols) symbol,
>   with attributes { [[Writable]]: **true**, [[Enumerable]]: **false**,
>   [[Configurable]]: **true** } and whose value is a [function
>   object](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#dfn-function-object). [...]
>
> If the interface defines an [indexed property getter](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#dfn-indexed-property-getter), then the
>   **Function** object is [%ArrayProto_values%](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-well-known-intrinsic-objects).

In this case, HTMLCollections have an indexed property getter:

```
getter Element? item(unsigned long index);
```

and an integer-typed attribute named “length”:

```
readonly attribute unsigned long length;
```

Therefore, yes, it's supposed to work. In fact, it would also work for NodeLists even if they weren't declared as iterable, but then they wouldn't have the `entries`, `forEach`, `keys` and `values` properties. As @lonesomeday mentions, it's probable that HTMLCollection is not defined as iterable because adding these methods wouldn't be backwards-compatible, due to the fact that the `namedItem` getter accepts arbitrary strings.

Comment: I'm going to *guess* it's because of either the `namedItem` method on an `HTMLCollection` or the statement "Note: Elements is the better solution for representing a collection of elements. HTMLCollection is an historical artifact we cannot rid the web of."

Comment: @lonesomeday Yes, it seems so, since `namedItem` accepts a string, adding properties like `forEach` could break things.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript practically everything that has a structure of an `iterable` can go through some iteration engine operations such as : `for..of` and `...spread`

Anything is iterable if it returns an iterator for `[[Get]]` operations against a property that it stored `@@iterator` symbol which in that case apparently `HTMLCollection` returns such an object.

An iterator is counted per se if it has a : `next() {method}:`, and two other optional methods as well that are

```
return() {method}: stops iterator and returns IteratorResult
throw() {method}: signals error and returns IteratorResult
```

This is an example of a complete custom object that is iterable.

```
    const calculations = {
      counting: 1,
      [Symbol.iterator]: function(){ return this; },
      next: function(){

        if(this.counting <= 3){

          return {
            value: this.counting++,
            done: false
          }
        }

        return { value: this.counting, done: true}
      }
    };

const data = ...calculations; // [1,2,3]
```

So in your case, as long as `HTMLCollection` returns a proper iterator you can apply `for..of` and `...spread`, but if you concern is wether this meets the specification than I have to tell you that I don't have a bachelor computer science degree yet :P

Comment: Thanks, I already knew about `@@iterator`, my concern is whether `HTMLCollection` is supposed to return a proper iterator

Comment: @Oriol I think this depends on the implementation. HTMLCollection interface has no declaration for an iterator but when implemented you can include another interface as well. In this case HTMLCollection and NodeList are a representation of collections that sure enough is iterable.