# Removing divs without removing their content in plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Could anyone help me on how I can remove `div` tags without removing their content in `JavaScript`?

This is my html from which I need to remove all div tags:

```
<div id="id1" class="someclass">
  <p>some text
    <label> Test content </label>
  </p>
  <div id="id2" style="overfolw:scroll">
    <span>some text</span>
    <div id="level3">
      <label> Test content </label>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/882186896285282304" target=_blank rel=noopener>creepiness</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Expected output would be like shown below.

```
<p>some text
   <label> Test content </label>
</p>
<span>some text</span>
<label> Test content </label>
<a href=https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/882186896285282304 target=_blank rel=noopener>creepiness</a>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

Comment: @Dij Why edit "plain javascript" into the title when the question is tagged [jquery]?

Comment: @CodesInChaos that has been tagged by OP but in one of the comments OP said, he can't use jQuery, so the title is more appropriate

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using pure java-script:

```js
var divs=document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var counter = divs.length-1;
for(i=counter;i>=0;i--){
 divs[i].outerHTML = divs[i].innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<div id="id1" class="someclass">
  <p>some text
    <label> Test content </label>
  </p>
  <div id="id2" style="overfolw:scroll">
    <span>some text</span>
    <div id="level3">
      <label> Test content </label>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/882186896285282304" target=_blank rel=noopener>creepiness</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using jQuery [unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div').contents().unwrap();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id1" class="someclass">
  <p>some text
    <label> Test content </label>
  </p>
  <div id="id2" style="overfolw:scroll">
    <span>some text</span>
    <div id="level3">
      <label> Test content </label>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/882186896285282304" target=_blank rel=noopener>creepiness</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `contents()` is much nicer than `div > *`. +1

Comment: @Phil  thanks for points.

Comment: @AlivetoDie cannot use jquery :-(

Comment: @UmairZahid  check once my edited solution

Answer (score 5):

Using cutting edge technology such as [iterable nodelists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31283360/1048572) and [`replaceWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith), it's really straightforward with the plain DOM API:

```
for (const div of document.querySelectorAll("div"))
// alternatively: Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("div"))
    div.replaceWith(...div.childNodes);
```

Comment: +1 However, you should mention directly in your post that this is not just _cutting  edge_ but _experimental_ technology, with **very limited browser compatibility** thus far. Good answer nevertheless.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `unwrap` function.

```
 $('div').children().unwrap();
```

If you want to do in plain javascript. You can get a list of all divs using `document.getElementsByTagName("div")`, but you will need to unwrap these divs in reverse order. This is a `nodelist` so `reverse()` will not work on it, so you can first use `[].slice.call()` on it which gives you an array and then you can reverse it. Then in the array unwrap each element.

you can do something like this:

```js
var elements = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("div"), 0).reverse();
elements.forEach(function(el){
    el.outerHTML = el.innerHTML;
});
```

```html
<div id="id1" class="someclass">
  <p>some text
    <label> Test content </label>
  </p>
  <div id="id2" style="overfolw:scroll">
    <span>some text</span>
    <div id="level3">
      <label> Test content </label>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/882186896285282304" target=_blank rel=noopener>creepiness</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```