# Unable to loop through HTMLCollection with forEach

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to assign a click event for each element that has a class name of `director__card--iconBox`. The way that I am selecting these elements is by `getElementsByClassName`. With the current code written, I am testing the function to apply a `background-color` of its parents div to red. The end goal is to be able to flip the div and to display the backside of the div that will come later.

```
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName("director__card--iconBox");

toggleButton.forEach((el) =>
  el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const card = event.target.parentElement.querySelector(".director__card");
    card.classList.toggle("open");
  })
);
```

I am getting back an HTMLCollection. My thoughts is that this won't work because of an HTMLCollection? I have tried querySelectorAll to bring back a Node List, yet the NodeList returns empty..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS: iterating over result of getElementsByClassName using Array.forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871547/js-iterating-over-result-of-getelementsbyclassname-using-array-foreach)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) is an array-like object but it does not have `forEach` method.

There are multiple ways you can iterate it with;

*e.g.*

Create an array out of it;

```
Array.from(toggleButton).forEach((el) =>
  el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const card = event.target.parentElement.querySelector(".director__card");
    card.classList.toggle("open");
  })
);
```

Use `for..of`

```
for (let item of toggleButton) {
    item.forEach((el) =>
        el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
            const card = event.target.parentElement.querySelector(".director__card");
            card.classList.toggle("open");
        });
    );
}
```

Or, just `for` loop.

```
for (let i = 0, len = toggleButton.length; i < len; i++) {
    toggleButton[i].forEach((el) =>
        el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
            const card = event.target.parentElement.querySelector(".director__card");
            card.classList.toggle("open");
        });
    );
}
```

Comment: I don't like "not iterable" when your own example shows `for of` usage.  See [Are HTMLCollection and NodeList iterables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31283360/are-htmlcollection-and-nodelist-iterables).

Comment: It has nothing to do with iteratable or not. The `HTMLCollection` interface just doesn't expose a `forEach` method. The `NodeList` interface does. This is also a duplicate question from 11 years ago...

Comment: It is now a question posted 11 years later. (y)

Comment: @MikeM I was not sure what's best to describe this old artifact. Thanks for pointing that out, I've updated the answer to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: You have a bug here. In `let i = 0, len = toggleButton.length`, `len` is not a `let` variable.   I put this code into a recursively walking function, and it didn't work because of this! The recursive levels assigned to `len`, causing the higher level not to iterate over all the items.

Answer (score 3):

The reason `querySelectorAll` wasn't returning anything was because you didn't add a `.` at the start (remember, `querySelectorAll` accepts a [DOMString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString) that must a valid [CSS Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)). This caused it return an array of elements with the tag name `director__card--iconBox` instead of an array of elements with the class `director__card--iconBox`.

Try the following:

```
const toggleButton = document.querySelectorAll(".director__card--iconBox");

toggleButton.forEach((el) =>
  el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const card = event.target.parentElement.querySelector(".director__card");
    card.classList.toggle("open");
  })
);
```