# Append NodeList to HTML element

Tags: javascript, dom

I have the following string:

```
var songlist = '<div class="list-item" id="57902ccae53fa51716424034"><div class="media"><img src="{imgsrc}" alt="Mama Tried" /></div><h4 class="title">Mama Tried</h4><div class="song-controls"><button class="song play"><span class="fa fa-play"></button></div></div><div class="list-item" id="57902cddae7b54e264fcc6e4"><div class="media"><img src="{imgsrc}" alt="Blue Eyes Crying In the Rain" /></div><h4 class="title">Blue Eyes Crying In the Rain</h4><div class="song-controls"><button class="song play"><span class="fa fa-play"></button></div></div>';
```

Which I am converting to a NodeList through this custom function:

```
var toDom = function(str) {
  var tmp = document.createElement("div");
  tmp.innerHTML = str;
  return tmp.childNodes;
};
```

`console.log(toDom(songlist))` outputs `NodeList [ <div#57902ccae53fa51716424034.list-item>, <div#57902cddae7b54e264fcc6e4.list-item> ]`, which you can browse through the devtools.

When I try to append the collection to a node...

```
document.getElementById("app-data").appendChild(toDom(songlist));
```

I get `TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild does not implement interface Node.` Which is odd, because the [docs for `Node.appendChild()`](https://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#appendChild_org.w3c.dom.Node_) say that argument 1 must be of type Node.

So, what type of element does Node.appendChild() expect? I've also tried HTMLCollection.

[See JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ffvfes0w/3/).

Comment: Node, and you are appending NodeList.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that [Node.childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) is a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). So when you try to append it, it fails of course, because NodeList is not the same as [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node). You could append child nodes one by one in loop:

```
var container = document.getElementById("app-data");
var childNodes = toDom(songlist);

for (var i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
    container.appendChild(childNodes[i])
}
```

Comment: Document fragment should be used instead of multiple append. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14910308/1213633

Answer (score 10):

now, you can use element.append() and element.childNodes straightly. just like:

```js
var container = document.getElementById("app-data");
var childNodes = toDom(songlist);
container.append(...childNodes)
function toDom(str) {
  var tmp = document.createElement("div");
  tmp.innerHTML = str;
  return tmp.childNodes;
};
```

Comment: To me, this is the better answer. Shouldn't down vote without a reason.
I'm unsure whether you can use a spread operator on a nodelist though since it is not an array.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append
I like the document fragment answer even better.

Comment: Just tested. Apparently nodeList is spreadable. (**...nodeList**)

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would use the `<template>` tag. It inherits from Element and it has a nifty HTMLTemplateElement.content property that gives you a DocumentFragment which can be appended directly into another element.

```js
var container = document.getElementById("app-data");
var childNodesFragment = stringToFragment(songlist);
container.appendChild(childNodesFragment);

function stringToFragment(string) {
    var renderer = document.createElement('template');
    renderer.innerHTML = string;
    return renderer.content;
};
```