# Error using insertBefore & appendChild while creating element

Tags: javascript

Trying to append a button to both the top and bottom of the body tag, however it's only performing whichever one of the two is last. Am I missing something obvious here?

```
var msg_node = document.createElement("a");
msg_node.setAttribute("onclick", "collapseAll()");
msg_node.setAttribute("href", "javascript:void(0)");
msg_node.setAttribute("class", "kc_button");
var msg_textnode = document.createTextNode('COLLAPSE ALL');
msg_node.appendChild(msg_textnode);
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(msg_node);  // supposed to make button
document.body.insertBefore(msg_node, document.body.children[0]); // makes only this button
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add multiple divs with appendChild?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910196/how-to-add-multiple-divs-with-appendchild) - As the accepted answer here states, you've only created *one* element. If you want to create two, you need to call `createElement` twice.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Can I do something like `var msg_node_2 = msg_node;` or do i have to repeat the entire code over again?

Comment: You can do `var msg_node_2 = msg_node.cloneNode(true);` as Matansh's answer points out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clone the node before appending it the second time:

```
var msg_node = document.createElement("a");
msg_node.setAttribute("onclick", "collapseAll()");
msg_node.setAttribute("href", "javascript:void(0)");
msg_node.setAttribute("class", "kc_button");
var msg_textnode = document.createTextNode('COLLAPSE ALL');
msg_node.appendChild(msg_textnode);
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(msg_node);  // supposed to make button
document.body.insertBefore(msg_node.cloneNode(true), document.body.children[0]); // makes only this button
```

Comment: by cloning, can I do something like `var msg_node_2 = msg_node;`?

Comment: No, because msg_node is an object, and copy its reference into a new variable won't do the trick.
The cloneNode works great, try it.

Comment: By the way, cloneNode will also copy the onclick, href and class attributes, if that is what you are worry about.

Comment: cloneNode worked perfectly! Thank you. As per the docs, it copied all children (attributes, etc).