# JavaScript’s element.appendChild() method behaving weird

Tags: javascript, appendchild

What i am trying to do is.. appending a common node/element in 3 elements..

```
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName(“test”);
const newElement = document.createElement(“BUTTON”);
newElement.classList.add(“dummy”);

Array.from(elements).forEach(item => {
item.appendChild(newElement);
});
```

Expected behaviour is that all `.test` elements should contain `.dummy` button..

but actually only last `.test` element getting that `.dummy` button..

But if i place that button in loop like this :

```
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName(“test”);

Array.from(elements).forEach(item => {
const newElement = document.createElement(“BUTTON”);
newElement.classList.add(“dummy”);
item.appendChild(newElement);
});
```

then all `.test` elements get that `.dummy` button..!!

Can anyone explain any particular reason about this JS behaviour ? I have tried to google it but didn’t find any good explanation about this.

Comment: You're adding the *same* element multiple times. You cannot have a node with multiple parents in the DOM, so you're just moving it from one to the next.

Comment: Did you check the documentation? "*If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, appendChild() moves it from its current position to the new position*" [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild). It even repeats the same thing in the very next paragraph: "*This means that a node can't be in two points of the document simultaneously. So if the node already has a parent, the node is first removed, then appended at the new position*"

Comment: Thanks a lot for the smooth explanation..!! Post it as answer

Comment: Yes completely explained the concept.. it’ll help others as well..!!

Comment: Also related: [How to add multiple divs with appendChild?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910196/how-to-add-multiple-divs-with-appendchild)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @VLAZ
Posting it as an answer :

If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, appendChild() moves it from its current position to the new position" from MDN. It even repeats the same thing in the very next paragraph: "This means that a node can't be in two points of the document simultaneously. So if the node already has a parent, the node is first removed, then appended at the new position

Answer (score 2):

That is because a child dom can only have one parent as dom is a tree structure and child node cannot inherit from multiple parents. In your case you are trying to assign multiple parent to the child node`newElement`.

Inside the array every time a new child is created and it has only single parent